# Jobs "type" and ambiguous search keywords

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I just tried jobs for the first time and searched for the word `frontend` and chose contract positions:

There were 2 results, [one of which was this](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/102261/engineering-interns-python-and-or-mean-stack-stratagem-technologies-ltd?searchTerm=frontend&offset=0&ajax=1&type=contract)

There's no mention of the word contract anywhere in the post and one reference in the body for the word `frontend`, which was basically talking about the company stack as much as anything.

I haven't looked, posted, but would have thought there would be tags for `contract` and `frontend` which is what would actually be searched?

Searching the body for keywords is a challenge as lots of posts will talk about `front end` || `frontend` even if they are back end positions.

If the position "type" is not required when posting a job (again, haven't looked), it should be. I do contracts and am simply not interested in anything else. As are some permanent employees, probably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Position type is an attributes of a job listing. Employers can choose *permanent* or *contract* for it, or *unspecified* if the job is open to both:

[image]

Search results will be filtered accordingly if a job type is chosen in the dropdown:

[image]

For searching for front-end jobs, employers typically add more specific tags to their job listing, such as [HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=html5) or [CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=css3). Searching for those more specific tags is likely to return more relevant results to you.

Finally, you can also fine-tune the jobs showing up in the "matches" tab by editing your match preferences (click the little gear next to "matches", you'll have to be signed in with your Stack Overflow account):

[image]

Good luck!